# Restore Nuget package from url MSBUILD xml

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm building install script using MSBuild.exe. I have 3 Nuget Package which the script should restore but it ignores them I don't know why.

This is my XML code for MSBuild

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Start"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <SourceFolder>..\myfolder</SourceFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Start">
    <CallTarget Targets="Build"/>
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.4.0" />        
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.4.0" />                
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild 
            Projects="$(SourceFolder)\mysolution.sln"
            Properties="Configuration=Release"
            Targets="Restore;Clean;Build"
            ContinueOnError="false"
            StopOnFirstFailure="true"
    >

    </MSBuild>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `PackageReference` is mostly used in `.csproj` file and when you build the project it the packages would be downloaded as per the `packages.config` file and `nuget.config` file. So you do not need to have `PackageReference` in MSBuild script. When the MSBuild will build the solution, the required nuget packages will be downloaded based on their use in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: But when I remove the packages and run MSBuild from a batch file, nothing is downloaded, I don't know why!!

Comment: ok.. I got it.. whatever I said earlier does not hold good when you build the solution by msbuild. You need to restore the nuget packages manually by running `nuget restore <yoursolution>.sln -configFile ./nuget.config` command. You can run this command from msbuild script itself before building the solution... as following. `<Exec Command="nuget restore $(SourceFolder)\mysolution.sln -configFile $(SourceFolder)\nuget.config" />`